# show sign out button after successfull login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using mvc3 application where after click on login button i am checking that user is validated or not using ajax call in jquery. If user is authenticated then i return true and in Onsuccess method i am redirecting it to home page. Below is the code:

```html
function OnSuccess(response) {
    var mesg = $("#lblMess")[0];
   
    switch (response) {
        case true:
            var url = "/Home/Search";
            takeToHomePage(url);
            $(location).attr('href', url);
            
            break;
        case false:
            mesg.style.color = "red";
            mesg.innerHTML = "Email id or Password is incorrect";
            break;
        case "error":
            mesg.style.color = "red";
            mesg.innerHTML = "Error occured";
            break;
    }
}
```

Till here working fine. Now i added one signout button in _layout.cshtml page which i made visibility none in login page, so if i show this signout button before switch starts and user is not valid then signout button displays but if user is authenticated and trying to show signout button inside true case then it is not working.
Need help.

Comment: Why are you using ajax if the intention is to redirect. Its pointless. Just do a normal submit and redirect.

Comment: Are you using forms authentication?

Comment: yes Reddy, it's a forms authentication

Answer (score 0):

> Now i added one signout button in _layout.cshtml page which i made
>   visibility none in login page, so if i show this signout button before
>   switch starts and user is not valid then signout button displays but
>   if user is authenticated and trying to show signout button inside true
>   case then it is not working.

Make a Ajax call to server to check if user is authenticated or not. And then you can toggle the button show and hide. `This is not the best method to do it. But talking about good approach would be to create a custom CustomPrincipal by inheriting ICustomPrincipal and may more changes`. which I think would be too much for you if you have just started on MVC.

This solution is only to toggle the sign-out button visibility and I am not proposing this as best practise.

```
 $.get("User/CheckUserAuthenticity",function(response){
     if(response == "true")
      {
        //button show;
      }
  });
```

your Controller Action can be

```
    public ActionResult CheckUserAuthenticity()
    {
      return Json(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Here the added message in last is if user is authenticated then inside true case i am trying to hide signin button and show signout button but it is not happening it is still showing sign in button only.

Comment: signin button id = $("#signin").css("display","none");                      SignOut button id = $("#signout").css("display","block"); this is working fine i use this code before starts true and false case (inside switch only) but when i use this code inside true case it is not working.

Comment: Did you use the code which I have suggested above? Also It would be better if you can update your question with your current code and problem.

Comment: The code which you have suggested that is not a best practice commented by you only and second thing is that when will it be called?